# iOS mapview multiple address using searchbar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mkmapview

i'm totally new to iOS `MapView`, i have just created `mapview` and `uisearchbar` **outlets**, where if i type a word in search bar the PIN shows the exact place i have done this using,

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar 
{
    NSMutableString *urlString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@?output=json",inAddress];

    [urlString setString:[urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request  delegate:self];

}
```

Finally the function to zoom my map, which should by now be a trivial thing.

```
- (void) zoomMapAndCenterAtLatitude:(double) latitude andLongitude:(double) longitude
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude  = latitude;
    region.center.longitude = longitude;

    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = .005;
    span.longitudeDelta = .005;
    region.span = span;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

but if there are **more than one places matches the search bar keyword** multiple **PIN** has to be shown..
Example : If i type **HOSPITALS in Washington**, hospitals near Washington has to be shown
 is it possible here..? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Where are you adding pin/annotation on map?
You can add multiple annotations on map view using addAnnotations: method of MKMapView.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html

Comment: how to search a map using the word entered in the search bar..?

Comment: You can use Google places API with Map Kit:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit